# Almacenar el valor que retorna FETCH

Tags: nodejs

Ahora estoy intentando obtener el dato (resultado) después del FETCH...

Sin embargo, no he podido almacenar en una variable el dato que se recibe en función al realizar el FETCH.. (el último folio de presupuestos)..

```
       const url = 'http://localhost:3001/presupuestos/fetch'
                        
            extraePresEnca = async () => {
                try {
                    let respuesta = await fetch(url)
                    let json = await respuesta.json()
                    vFolioPresX = json[0].folio
                    console.log(vFolioPresX)                    
                    return vFolioPresX
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('Mensaje de error: '+error)
                }
            }
```

Esto es lo que intento... :

```
            /* var vFolioPresupuesto = async() => {
                try {
                    let respuesta = await fetch(url)
                    //console.log('Dato en respuesta: ')
                    //console.log(respuesta)

                    let json = await respuesta.json()
                    //console.log('Dato en respuesta.json: ')
                    //console.log(json)
                    
                    console.log('Dato en respuesta.json VALOR..: ')
                    vFolioPresX = json[0].folio
                    console.log(vFolioPresX)
                    
                    //return json                     
                    return vFolioPresX + 1                   
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log('Mensaje de error: '+error)
                }
            } */

            let vFolioPresupuesto =  async function getFolioX() {
                let result = await extraePresEnca();
                return result + 1;
            }

            console.log('Folio por asignar: '+vFolioPresupuesto)
```

Sigo al pendiente..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías definir primero definir la variable donde quieres guardarlo y con un `then` lo guardas,
algo asi

```
// La variable donde vamos a guardar el folio
let folio;

extraePresEnca = async () => {
  const url = 'http://localhost:3001/presupuestos/fetch'
  try {
      let respuesta = await fetch(url)
      let json = await respuesta.json()
      vFolioPresX = json[0].folio
      console.log(vFolioPresX)                    
      return vFolioPresX + 1  // Le sumamos el 1 aqui mismo
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('Mensaje de error: '+error)
  }
}
// El código extra
extraePresEnca()
.then((res)=>{
  folio = resutado;
})
.catch(e=>console.error(e))
```

Aunque al ser asincrónico el código siguiente a estos pasos te puede dar problemas, lo mejor es que en el mismo `then` hagas lo que tengas que hacer con el resultado.

Además podrías saltarte la función `vFolioPresupuesto` y directamnte sumarle el `1` en la primera función.

Comment: con lo que compartes recibo esto:

Folio por asignar: undefined

Comment: Es por ser código asincronico. Porque al imprimir la variable folio no ha terminado de ejecutar el fetch. En cambio el `then` se ejecuta después de terminar el fetch. Por eso te recomiendo que en el mismo then proceses la variable. Te doy [link](https://jonmircha.com/javascript-asincrono) sobre código asincronico

Answer (score 0):

Josephdavid07 contestando a lo que comentas, además...

He estado trabajando con algo parecido y recibo esto:

Folio por asignar: [object Promise]

3

Este es el código:

```
let  vFolioPresupuesto = extraePresEnca().then(
                async (res)=>{
                    vFolioX = await res
                    console.log(vFolioX)
                    return vFolioX
                }
            )
```